# How do I draw horizontal bars with a label using either ChartJS or D3?

Tags: d3.js, graph, chart.js

What's the best way of drawing multiple horizontal lines and labels for a simple line graph in either ChartJS or D3? I know that I could draw these as individual lines and then do a text overlay but I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution. Ideally I'd be able to create each of the labels below as one unit and move it anywhere.

If this is simpler in another JS graph library then feel free suggest.

Example below

[image: Horizontal Labels]

Comment: You can group the bar and text in a `g` in SVG.

Comment: @tomasz - when you meant "move it anywhere." do you mean programmatically or drag and drop?

Comment: @potatopeelings programmatically

Answer (score 2):

To do it with Chart.js you have to extend the line chart

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        // it's easier to programmatically update if you store the raw data in the object (vs. storing the geometric data)
        this.marks = data.marks;
        this.marks.xStart = Number(data.labels[0]);
        this.marks.xStep = data.labels[1] - data.labels[0];

        // make sure all our x labels are uniformly apart
        if (!data.labels.every(function (e, i, arr) { return !i || ((e - arr[i - 1]) === this.marks.xStep); }, this))
            throw "labels must be uniformly spaced";

        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        // save existing context properties
        var self = this;
        var ctx = self.chart.ctx;
        var scale = self.scale;

        ctx.save();
        // line properties
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#666";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
        ctx.font = scale.font;

        // draw marks
        self.marks.forEach(function (mark) {
            // assuming that the marks are always within the data range
            var y = scale.calculateY(mark.y);
            var x1 = scale.calculateX((mark.x1 - self.marks.xStart) / self.marks.xStep);
            var x2 = scale.calculateX((mark.x2 - self.marks.xStart) / self.marks.xStep);

            // draw line
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x1, y);
            ctx.lineTo(x2, y);
            // draw edges
            ctx.moveTo(x1, y + 10);
            ctx.lineTo(x1, y - 10);
            ctx.moveTo(x2, y + 10);
            ctx.lineTo(x2, y - 10);
            ctx.stroke();

            // draw text
            ctx.fillText(mark.label, (x1 + x2) / 2, y + scale.fontSize * 1.5);
        })

        ctx.restore();
    },
});
```

You pass in the data for drawing the lines like so

```
var data = {
    ...
    marks: [
        {
            x1: 1.5,
            x2: 3.5,
            y: 50,
            label: 'Label1'
        },
        {
            x1: 5,
            x2: 7,
            y: 60,
            label: 'Label2'
        }
    ]
};
```

and you create the chart using this extended chart type

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

You can update the lines like this

```
myLineChart.marks[0].y = 80;
myLineChart.marks[0].x1 = 9;
myLineChart.marks[0].x2 = 10;
```

and then call

```
myLineChart.update();
```

to reflect those changes on the canvas

---

**Caveats**

1. The (x axis) labels should be numeric and uniformly spaced.
2. The lines should be within the scale range of the y axis (alternatively you can do a scaleOverride to set the scale parameters so that the lines are within the y scale range)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/en92k763/2/

---

[image]